# Repeatedly fetching a URL until the response contains "state: INIT"

Tags: regex, bash, http, linux, shell

I am working on a project in which I need to make a URL call to one of my servers from a bash shell script.

```
 http://hostname.domain.com:8080/beat
```

After hitting the above URL, I will be getting the below response, from which I need to parse and extract the value of `state`:

```
num_retries_allowed: 3 count: 30 count_behind: 100 state: INIT num_rounds: 60 hour_col: 2 day_col: 0
```

Now I will keep on hitting the above URL every 10 seconds until the value of the state variable is equal to `INIT`:

```
state = INIT
```

If the `state` is equal to `INIT` then I will exit successfully out of the shell script, otherwise I will keep on trying until the state becomes `INIT`.

Also, if the `state:` string is missing in the `$DATA` variable by any chance, then I want to assign `0` to the `state` variable. So if `state` is equal to `0`, then I will also exit out of the shell script successfully.

I am hitting the above URL and checking whether I got a successful response or not. If I got a successful response, then I am breaking out (which means server is running fine), but if I didn't got successful response, then I am checking whether my server is running or not on port 8080. If it is not running, then I will start the server. And I am retrying this for a period of 15 times, and after 15 tries if the server hasn't come back up, then exit out of the shell script with a non-zero status code.

Is the below shell script correct?

```
#!/bin/bash

HOSTNAME=$hostname
DATA=""
RETRY=15

echo $HOSTNAME

sleep 1m

while true; do

    while [ $RETRY -gt 0 ]
    do
        DATA=$(wget -O - -q -t 1 http://$HOSTNAME:8080/beat)
        if [ $? -eq 0 ]
        then
            break
        else
            if lsof -Pi :8080 -sTCP:LISTEN -t >/dev/null ;
            then
                echo "Server is running"
            else
                echo "Server is not running so re-starting the server here"
                # starting server here
            fi
            let RETRY-=1
            sleep 30
        fi
    done

    if [ $RETRY -eq 0 ]
    then
        echo "Server is still down. Exiting out now." >&2
        exit 2
    fi

    echo "Server is up. Now parsing the data out of the beat."

    #grep $DATA for state
    state=$(grep -oP 'state: \K\S+' <<< "$DATA")
    [[ -z "$state" ]] && state=0

    echo $state

    #verify the condiitons
    if [[ $state -eq "INIT" || $state -eq "0" ]]; then exit 0; fi

    #wait another 10 seconds
    sleep 10

done
```

Is there any better way of doing this if I am doing anything wrong?

Comment: Is `$hostname` set in your environment, or is that just an example?

Comment: Yes its being set externally. I have tested that and it works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of grepping for `state`, I would use bash regex support:

```
    re='state: ([A-Z]*)'
    state=0
    [[ "$DATA" =~ $re ]] && state=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
```

Comment: I know this is an old post, but why would you use Bash Regex instead of Grep?

Comment: @Malachi the Bash regex check is performed within the same Bash process. `grep` would be an extra process

Answer (score 2):

#### Inconsistent logic

In one place the script checks `http://$HOSTNAME:8080/beat`,
in another, it checks for a local process listening on port 8080.
This only makes sense if `$HOSTNAME` the name of the local machine.
It will make more sense to replace `$HOSTNAME` with hard-coded `localhost`.

#### Use exit code directly

Instead of this:

> ```
> DATA=$(wget -O - -q -t 1 http://$HOSTNAME:8080/beat)
> if [ $? -eq 0 ]
> then
>     break
> ```

You could use the exit code directly like this:

```
if DATA=$(wget -O - -q -t 1 http://$HOSTNAME:8080/beat)
then
    break
```

Another way:

```
DATA=$(wget -O - -q -t 1 http://$HOSTNAME:8080/beat) && break
```

#### Math in Bash

Instead of this:

> ```
> let RETRY-=1
> ```

There are slightly simpler alternatives:

```
((RETRY -= 1))
((RETRY--))
```

Answer (score 0):

> > Is $hostname set in your environment ...
>
> Yes its being set externally.

Maybe consider using a command line argument, that's a bit more obvious.

The inner `while` loop could be replaced with a `for` loop for counting.  And `curl` defaults to stdout, so you could use that instead of `wget`.

Now, since you're using `lsof` the server is running on your machine, right?  In that case you should probably have the PID of the server process somewhere or you can also use `ps`/`pgrep` to check whether it is running (before restarting it I mean).

Rest looks good I think.